# Go to a specific selection in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html page with jquery, javascript. I use apache webserver and if I put direct URL in browser works fine for ex: localhost/mysite/index.html but if i use a part of the page let us say I have a div (clickable button or panel) on clicking it should redirect to another page.But if I try to access in browser the page using "localhost/mysite/index.html#clicable" then it redirects to the index page, but not to the page it supposed to redirect to for the first time, but once the clickable is already clicked, from then the browser URL with # at end works fine. All I need is when I access through address bar with # at end it should redirects to the page it supposed to.
TIA

Comment: have you use <a name="clicable"></a> in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<a name="clicable"></a>
```

To any part of your page

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an anchor `<a name="clicable"></a>` mentioned already, you can also give any element an `id` of "clicable" to scroll directly to it from the hash in the URL, eg: `<h2 id="clicable">Text</h2>`.